# How to change input element's visibility through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For  tag the below code is working fine, but for `<input>` isn't. Can you guide me how to solve it?

html:

```
<span id="toValue">AND</span>
<input id="toValue">
```

css:

```
#toValue {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

js:

```
$('#toValue').css("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: id is singular... only one element, use a class

Comment: invalid markup same ids on two elements.

Comment: Let's think of elements as people, ids as personal IDs and classes as jobs. Two people can't have the same ID but they can have the same job. This is the same with elements

Comment: Thank you guys, I am new to UI development(stack over flow also). Learning it by doing, it seems very much basic question. Even though you answered for it. It is really appreciable. If i committed any mistakes while asking a question please remind me, i will correct my self.

Answer (score 2):

Don't repeat the same `id` in the same page. Change it to a class:

```
.toValue {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Html:

```
<span class="toValue">AND</span>
<input class="toValue">
```

Then:

```
$('.toValue').css("visibility", "visible");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azc55v18/).

Or use different ids to each element:

```
<span class="toValue" id="mySpan">AND</span>
<input class="toValue" id="myInput">
```

Then:

```
$('#mySpan, #myInput').css("visibility", "visible");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azc55v18/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to UI, so i asked very basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is invalid: two elements with the same `id`. Use `class` instead:

HTML

```
<span class="toValue">AND</span>
<input class="toValue">
```

CSS:

```
.toValue {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ids must be unique for elements. the first element with that particular id will always be updated and the other discarded so either use the "class" attribute or change the ids

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Same ids to multiple elements in a single page makes an invalid markup and that is hard to work when you try using js with those elements.

> *For tag the below code is working fine, but for `<input>` isn't.*
>
> It is because:
> Browser stops the lookup at first element found and don't go next to look for another one.
> <sub>***NOTE:- If you try check the length of your selector it would always return 1.***</sub>

Solution to this is that you change the id to class attribute and the css as well:

```
.toValue {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and

```
<span class="toValue">AND</span>
<input class="toValue">
```

in js:

```
$('.toValue').css("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique, Either you can also use class if you want to use common selector, here is demo of simple show and hide of your elements

```js
function func1(){
  $("#spanValue").hide();
  $("#inputValue").hide();
}

function func2(){
  $("#spanValue").show();
  $("#inputValue").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="spanValue">AND</span>
<input id="inputValue" type="text">
<input type="button" onClick="func1();" value="Hide">
<input type="button" onClick="func2();" value="Show">
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable info. I am new to UI , so i asked very basic question i think.